# Standard representation, irreducibility and Cayley's theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

If $ (\pi, V) $ is the standard representation of the group $S_n$, where $V = \{ \sum^{n}x_ie_i \mid \sum_n x_i = 0 \}$ and this representation is irreducible.

According to [Cayley's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_theorem), every group is isomorphic to a subgroup of some symmetric group. Assume that $ G \cong H \leq S_n $.

Can we then conlude that $ (\pi, V) $
is also an irreducible representation of $H$, since every argument that $ (\pi, V) $ is an irreducible representation of $S_n$ also applies to $H$, and due to the isomorphism, it is also an irreducible representation of $G$?

If this is true, then an approach to find a representation space of one irreducible representation, is to find the corresponding isomorphism to the subgroup of $S_n$?

For instance, $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{F}_4) \cong A_5 \leq S_5$, and $A_5$ has the same representation space as $S_5$ for the standard representation. So, in this case it was sufficient enough to find the isomorphism to find the representation space, but I do not know if this is true in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not true. Take an abelian group, such as $\Bbb Z_3$. It is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_3$, in which case $\dim V=2$. In particular, $\dim V>1$. Therefore, $V$ is not an irreducible representation of $\Bbb Z_3$, since every irreducible representation of a finite abelian group is $1$-dimensional.

In general, if $(\pi,V)$ is an irreducible representation of a group $G$ and if $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, $\left(\pi_H,V\right)$ is not an irreducible representation of $H$.

Comment: I see, in the case of an abelian group it's troublesome. However, are there any results or theorems about when this is true, for non-abelian groups ofcourse?

Comment: I used abelian groups because it was easier to explain in that case. But if you see $S_3$ as a subgroup of $S_4$, then $V$ is a $3$-dimensional representation of $S_4$ and there are no $3$-dimensional irreducible represntations of $S_3$.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Thanks for the disproving examples!